# Why is my $watch showing an array that appears to be empty?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on creating an AngularJS directive in order to use D3 to render a visualization, but I'm running into problems when it comes to setting a `$watch`.  The majority of my stuff looks extremely similar to the AngularJS tutorial.  My resources are configured in a file called `resources.json`, which I'm sure is returning correctly.

Here's the relevant code of what I have so far:

app.js

```
var resourceApp = angular.module("resourceApp", [
    'ngRoute',
    'resourceControllers',
    'resourceDirectives',
    'resourceServices'
]);

/* ... routing config ... */
```

controllers.js

```
var resourceControllers = angular.module('resourceControllers', []);

resourceControllers.controller("OverviewCtrl", [ '$scope', 'Resource',
    function($scope, Resource) {
        $scope.resources = Resource.query();
    }
]);

/* ... other controllers ... */
```

directives.js

```
var resourceDirectives = angular.module('resourceDirectives', []);

resourceDirectives.directive("resourceVisualization", function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
          resources: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
          // svg setup is here

          scope.$watch("resources", function(nRes, oRes) {
              if (nRes) {
                 // this logs an array of Resource objects 
                 //(once expanded in Firebug)
                 console.log(nRes);

                 var cats = nRes.map(function(r) { return r.category; });
                 // this logs an empty array
                 console.log(cats);
               }
           });
      }
   };
 });
```

overview.html

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="resource in resources">
      {{resource.name}}
   </li>
</ul>
<resource-visualization resources="resources"></resource-visualization>
```

resources.json (which is what services.js is configured to pull from)

```
[
 {
   "id": 1,
   "category": "test",
   "type": "sample",
   "name": "Test1"
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "category": "test",
   "type": "sample4",
   "name": "Test2"
 },
 {
   "id": 3,
   "category": "fake",
   "type": "sample1",
   "name": "Test3"
 },
 {
   "id": 4,
   "category": "new",
   "type": "sample2",
   "name": "Test4"
 }]
```

Now, I know that the REST call is working, because the `<ul>` is populated.  However, in the directive, the logging statements are returning empty arrays.  I'm aware of the the async-ness of `$resource`, but the object that is logged first in the `$watch` contains `$resolved: true`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you 100% sure nRes is an array? Have you tried sticking a log in the callback function you're passing to map to see it's iterating over each element?

Comment: Also, are you sure that `nRes` has items that contain `category`.  Really, what does nRes look like.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet:  Yes, its definitely an array.  The `console.log(nRes)` statements shows up as an array in Firebug.  @TheSharpieOne:  Updating the question now to show what the JSON file for resources (which populates `nRes` looks like.

Comment: I guess `nRes` is an Promise object which gets resolved into Array. Try moving map() inside the success callback.

Comment: @AdityaJain I moved the map() inside there, and it was able to pull out the categories. Any advice on getting it to work inside of the `$watch`, though?

Comment: what output do you see in the con`sole if you write console.log(nRes.length); instead of console.log(nRes); ?

Comment: @Michael Its returning a 0.  I'm guessing that's because its an empty array that hasn't been filled yet.  But why would it do that in the `$watch`?

Comment: @Pat Yes this is the first change to your scope data: $scope.resources = Resource.query(); e.g. the initial value of $scope.resources. please have a look at the $watchCollection (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope) this would be better for your needs.

Comment: @Michael  Nice!  `$watchCollection` was the answer.  If you submit it as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all fine. Your call to `Resource.query()` returns immediately an empty array. If the ajax call returns the real data, your array will be filled with the arrived data. So the first assignment to `$scope.resources` fires your `$watch` function with an empty array. You my solve your problem if you are using the  `$watchCollection` function. See [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) for further information.

Comment: Since it was a collection, `$watchCollection` was what I needed. Thanks again!